# ajax json working on local but not on remote server codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Visit [here](http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter) and the search bar in front is the autocomplete 
it is working fine when I use on localhost and appends results in the li under but when I have uploaded on live server it shows `404`.

[This](http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter/autocomplete/GetCompanyName) is the link to ***custom.js*** on which browser shows `404();`

***Main***: Custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#CompanyName").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter/autocomplete/GetCompanyName",
        data: {
            keyword: $("#CompanyName").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#Dropdowncompany').empty();
                $('#CompanyName').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                $('#Dropdowncompany').dropdown('toggle');
                alert("i am here");
            }
            else if (data.length == 0) {
                $('#CompanyName').attr("data-toggle", "");
            }
            $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                if (data.length >= 0)
                    $('#Dropdowncompany').append('<li role="displayCompanies" 
                   id="displayCompanies" ><a role="menuitem 
                   dropdowncompanyli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + 
                   value['CompanyName'] + '</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
$('ul.txtcompany').on('click', 'li a', function () {
    $('#CompanyName').val($(this).text());
    var CompanyName = $(this).text();
    alert(CompanyName); 
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/reviewotter/company2? 
    company="+CompanyName+"";
    //window.location.href = "http://localhost/reviewotter/company2? 
   lat="+elemA+"&lon="+elemB+"&setLatLon=Set";
});});
```

***Model***: datacomplete.php:

```
<?php
class Datacomplete extends CI_Model{
public function GetRow($keyword) {        
    $this->db->order_by('Id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->like("CountryName", $keyword);
    return $this->db->get('company')->result_array();
}}
```

***Controller***: autocomplete.php

```
<?php
class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('datacomplete');
}

public function index(){
    //$this->load->view('view_demo');
    $this->load->view('home');
}
public function GetCompanyName(){
    $keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
    $data=$this->datacomplete->GetRow($keyword);        
    echo json_encode($data);
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you notice you have `window.location.href = "http://localhost/reviewotter/company2?` hardcoded in your script?

Comment: window.location.href = "http://localhost/reviewotter/company2? 
    company="+CompanyName+""; update link

Comment: and also use `base_url` or `site_url` for the url path

Comment: its showing 404 error,check routes file

Comment: Check the console you have several errors, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null`, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null` and the one which relates to the autocomplete: `jquery.min.js:6 POST http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter/autocomplete/GetCompanyName 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: i have updated the link already it shows in google console that its searching for the same link as http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter/autocomplete/GetCompanyName  but no result

Comment: i have checked console for errors only the last one is related to autocomplete and i am not sure why is this happening
autocomplete is my controller and GetCompanyName is my function

Comment: please check Autocomplete controller exist on the server. Autocomplete controller it self is not loading. http://www.sonnify.de/reviewotter/autocomplete/ also giving 404 error

Comment: yes ajith it exist on remote server i think i am missing some route funcltionality, i am unable to understand because i am new to codeignitor but on the other hand if its working on localhost it should work on server too

Comment: Pleas note :  controller class and file should have  same name starting with caps, this can be the issue if not same

Comment: so upload your routes... by default CI looks for controller called "reviewotter" and method "autocomplete" as shown by your above code the controller is "autocomplete" so you indeed need a route. that is to say, that your ci install is not in a subfolder called "reviewotter" in which case there is another issue at work.

Comment: oh and just to piggy back off @pradeep... if your files are indeed called "autocomplete.php" then they should be changed to "Autocomplete.php" on windows it doesn't matter... but on linux servers (like most web servers) it does!

Comment: check the path of the file and also check base_path

Comment: Alex this is my routes file
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  $route['posts/create'] = 'posts/create';
  $route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
  $route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
  $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
  $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
  $route['404_override'] = '';
  $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: Alex and pradeep i have tried resolving the case sensitive issue also but no positive results
Note: my pages are in application/view/pages folder

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, localhost is on a Windows machine but the live server is Linux? Then it is probably a case sensitivity problem. Linux is a case-sensitive OS.

The model file `datacomplete.php` should be `Datacomplete.php` (Notice the uppercase first character?) and the controller `autocomplete.php` should be `Autocomplete.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get this resolved by adding a custom route. Please add below line to application/config/routes.php file.

```
$route['autocomplete/get-company-name'] = 'Autocomplete/GetCompanyName';
```

You will have to adjust your JQuery AJAX function according to the new URL. Also can remove the index.php from the URL. Please refer below link.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file